# cpanel pipe default system mail account

Tags: email, cpanel

In the cPanel forwarders option how to pipe a system default mail account?

For example if the system username is sample and the domain name is example.

Address to Forward: here a text box accepts the name and next to that is a list box which is the domain name and it is mandatory. so the email address will become sample@example.com but a system default mail id is not associated with @domainname.com i think

see the screen shot...

[image]

in that i can specify sample as the system default mail account but the list box shows the sitename.

so how to specify only the system default mail account to be forwarded to a piped program or to another email address ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the default email account is on a different screen. On the version of cPanel I'm using (11.30.5.2) it's called Default E-mail Account (under E-mail).